# how to remove uipangesture recognizer in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am new for iOS development. i don't know that how to remove uipangesture recognizer in iPhone. if any one knows Please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIView` class has an instance method called `-removeGestureRecognizer:`, which takes an `UIGestureRecognizer` as an argument. So if you have an `UIImageView` (`imgView` variable) for example and an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (`panRecognizer`) you can:

```
[imgView removeGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```